# mean(data.frame) in R is defunct, what are the alternatives?

Tags: r, mean

I am new in using R and I got this code sniplet from my supervisor:

```
for (i in 1:k) mean.mat[i, ] <- mean(data.frame[i])
```

However, as I found out, mean for data frames does not longer work. So I tried to come up with the following solution:

```
for (i in 1:k) mean.mat[i, ] <- lapply(norm.df[i], mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in mean.mat[i, ] <- lapply(norm.df[i], mean, na.rm = TRUE) : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

Does anybody know why this doesn't work and how I can replace the `mean()` function?

Comment: You need `mean(data.frame[,i])` in the first `for` loop because `data.frame[i]` is still a data.frame and not a `vector`.  The `mean` works on `vector`.  To convert it to a vector use the `,` before the 'i'.  In the second option, the `i` option and `for` loop is not needed when you are using `lapply` i.e. `lapply(norm.df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you akrun for your quick help! However, if I try the first solution for (i in 1:k) mean.mat[i, ] <- mean(norm.df[,i]) I still get the following error: Error in mean.mat[i, ] <- mean(norm.df[, i]) : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix. Trying the second solution I get the same error ("incorrect number of subscripts on matrix).

Comment: I think you need to initialize `mean.mat <- numeric(ncol(norm.df))` and then use `for(i in seq_len(ncol(norm.df))) { mean.norm[i] <- mean(norm.df[,i], na.rm=TRUE)}`

Comment: @akrun will you list this as an answer? Than Sabrina can accept the answer....

Comment: Just use `colMeans`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things that needs modification in the OP's code.

1. `for` loop

   a.  Use of `norm.df[i]` with `mean` is not going to work as `mean` works on `vector` instead of `data.frame`.  The `norm.df[i]` is still a `data.frame` while using a `,` and use column index on the rhs of it will convert it to `vector`.

   b.  The `mean` of all the columns can be concatenated to a `vector`.  So, if we initialize the output `vector` i.e. 'mean.norm' with `length` equal to the `ncol` of the 'norm.df', it will be easier

   ```
   mean.norm <- numeric(ncol(norm.df))
   ```

   c.  It is not clear whether 'k' is defined or not.  In case, it is not

   ```
   for(i in seq_len(ncol(norm.df))) {
        mean.norm[i] <- mean(norm.df[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
    }
   ```

   Note that the index used is `mean.norm[i]` instead of `mean.norm[i,]`.  For the latter, we need to have initialize 'mean.norm' as a `matrix` with a single column.
2. `lapply`

   Looping the columns with `lapply` doesn't need any index unless we are looping through the column names or the column numbers.

   ```
   lapply(norm.df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
   ```

The above output will be a `list`, but if we need a `vector` use `sapply`

```
  mean.norm <- sapply(norm.df, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

Or if we are looking for a compact and efficient code, `colMeans(norm.df, na.rm=TRUE)` (from @Roland's comment) can be used

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` based solution more inline with the `lapply` solution given by @Akrun:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat = data.frame(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
dat %>% gather(key, value) %>% group_by(key) %>% 
   summarise(mn = mean(value), stdev = sd(value))
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]

      key        mn     stdev
   (fctr)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1      X1 0.2817435 0.2795313
2      X2 0.4039304 0.3273860
3      X3 0.4994540 0.2612170
4      X4 0.4302393 0.3548886
5      X5 0.4095109 0.3707861
6      X6 0.4039782 0.2737998
7      X7 0.3985275 0.3672740
8      X8 0.5691146 0.2139044
9      X9 0.5315091 0.2943599
10    X10 0.5471878 0.3904215
```

I use `gather` to transform the dataset from wide to long format:

```
dat %>% gather(key, value) %>% head(15)
   key      value
1   X1 0.12273665
2   X1 0.04694209
3   X1 0.06572691
4   X1 0.87899058
5   X1 0.40901575
6   X1 0.63833813
7   X1 0.09088830
8   X1 0.18513657
9   X1 0.10783958
10  X1 0.27182005
11  X2 0.54010596
12  X2 0.03647860
13  X2 0.78629356
14  X2 0.96977616
15  X2 0.54121128
```